# Does Hour of Reckoning destroy enchantments?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Hour of Reckoning](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHour%20of%20Reckoning%5d) says

> Destroy all nontoken creatures.

Does this mean all Enchantments will be destroyed as well?

Comment: Coincidentally, similarly named card [Hour of Revelation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=430704) destroys all nonland permanents (including enchantments).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, enchantments are unaffected by Hour of Reckoning, unless they're also creatures, like [Nyx-Fleece Ram](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNyx-Fleece%20Ram%5d). ([Here](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?type=+%5B%22Enchantment%22%5D+%5B%22Creature%22%5D) are a couple of other enchantment creatures.) 'Creature' and 'Enchantment' are different permanent types in Magic.

Comment: In other words, it's "(non token) creatures", not "non (token creatures)".

Comment: Some permanents can also turn non-creature enchantments into creatures, e.g. Starfield of Nyx.

Comment: Any enchantments on creatures (enchant creature, enchant permanent that happens to be on a creature, or aura) would be put into the graveyard too (unless it specifically says otherwise).  For example, the enchantment creatures with Bestow that are in enchantment form on another creature, would remain in play is they are not creatures when hour of reckoning resolves.  There are also some enchant creature cards that return to your hand when they go to the graveyard from play (like Rancor).